# Способ обрезания много-строчного текста по высоте

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нашел хороший плагин на jQuery, однако он обрезает по символам, а мне надо по словам, если текст не вмещается, то вырезается и слово, а не символ. Вот привожу пример найденного плагина:

```js
(function($) {
  var truncate = function(el) {
    var text = el.text(),
      height = el.height(),
      clone = el.clone();

    clone.css({
      position: "absolute",
      visibility: "hidden",
      height: "auto"
    });
    el.after(clone);

    var l = text.length - 1;
    for (; l >= 0 && clone.height() > height; --l) {
      clone.text(text.substring(0, l) + "...");
    }

    el.text(clone.text());
    clone.remove();
  };

  $.fn.truncateText = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      truncate($(this));
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  $(".box").truncateText();
});
```

```css
.box {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <div class="box__in">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit
    augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Высота у блока задана, все что за пределами скрыто, зачем плагин то еще?

Comment: Точки... три точки на конце. Жестко надо сделать по макету, там три точи, на css увидел решение, но не подходит.

Comment: Добавляйте точки через псевдоэлемент

Comment: Вот он в цикле оставляет текст с 0 символа до l. Перед этим, когда он нашел место, где уже текст превышает высоту, нужно проверить соседние символы слева, и если они не 'пробел', то тоже вырезать, как только дошли до пробела, выполняем
clone.text(text.substring(0, l) + "..."); (с учитыванием того, что несколько символов еще могли удалить)

Comment: мне кажется проще сменить плагин. Взять скажем dotdotdot - он конечно пожирнее, но проблем с ним никаких, обрезает и по символам и по словам и как душе угодно только будет

Comment: MedvedevDev, спасибо вам большое, то что искал. Вот это ответ я принимаю и искренне вас благодарю!